I've printed a two columns word document, but texts overlaps where columns meet, on paper
How to fix overlapping first column text over second when printing. I tried to go "wrap text in columns" but that doesn't seem to be an option. My file shows as no text overlap but when I print printed text from column 1 goes a little into column 2.

To clarify, paragraphs for column 1 blend into columns 2 paragraphs where there's suppose to be a distinct separation between columns. It doesn't print as shown without overlapping columns/text. Is there an actual way to wrap text to their pertaining columns or do I have to adjust text manually?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Can you show us a screencap of the document and of the final printed page? You can upload them to http://imgur.com and link to them

Here is an image that shows incorrect print overlay in between columns shouldn't word correct this when printing https://tinypic.host/image/20240509-102730-%281%29-%284%29-%281%29.D8h6eH

Check the properties of each column -- in particular the tab settings.

I can't find a way to check or even select columns to see properties and couldn't find tab settings. I take it Word doesn't take text overlay considerations. I manually adjusted the ruler(I don't know what I did), but the document now prints only spills over single letter into the next column. Does column properties allow me to insert ruler settings?

Can you provide a link to the actual document. I suspect that the paragraph indents are wider than the columns.

Does the 2nd column start at the center line, or has its start moved to the left as well? I'm strongly suspecting that the layout is actually fine but the printer (or the printer driver) is rendering the text using a different font than what Word is submitting. (The printer is not aware of "columns" or "rulers" – it just gets the text already line-wrapped and laid out at specific (x,y) positions – but it is aware of fonts.)

Documents printing went copy plain .txt text>create new Word document>set two columns>paste. I've done this with two computers and printers with the same results, different texts same settings. I'm uploading the files if anyone is would like the ruler/setting width for end to end text per column(that I've moved the ruler manually) that doesn't seem to print over and the one that prints a few words into next columns text.

Here are the files one is named nooverlay which I manually adjusted the middle of ruler(I don't know too much about how ruler functions). Maybe its computer version only files not for printing aswell? I would like to know if I can change Word to neatly print two columns if I were to make a new file and paste and print. https://filebin.net/kk97jwtlcwkcrm75

Your paragraph indent settings are outside the boundaries of your columns.
You can see these when your insertion point is inside a column and you have the Ruler displayed.
Here is the Ruler in Column 1:

Here is Column 2:

These are paragraph settings, set in the style. In the Ruler you can see the limits for each column. The Left Indent in the text for each column is set outside the bounds of the column. While the columns are separate, the Right Indent of Column 1 and the Left Indent of Column 2 overlap.
Modify the style being used. Once in the Modify Style dialog, click on the Format button and then the Paragraph item to change these settings. Again, this is a paragraph format setting in the style, not a Column setting. It may have come in with the pasted text.
You could also select all the text in both columns, right click, and pick Paragraph from the Context menu. Modifying the style is preferable, though, to direct formatting. You can also apply changes to selected text, again as direct formatting, by moving the Indent markers in the Ruler when you have text selected.
Here is my writing on Indents and Margins in Word which I hope will help give you background.
Side Note: Your text is set for 5 points, which is smaller than the fine print in legal contracts. Don't expect anyone to read it.
